# Calling a virtual method from the base class

Tags: c++, opengl, polymorphism, glfw

So, basically I am creating a wrapper class that creates a simple OpenGL application. My idea is to have something like this when ready:

```
#include "application.h"
#include "myClassDerivedFromApp.h"
int main()
{ 
    myClassDerivedFromApp app(1024, 768, "My App Name", 3.3 /*OpenGL Version*/);
    app.start();
    return 0;
}
```

So, basically this class encapsulates a simple OpenGL window, using GLFW. The idea is that when you want to create a new application, you just derive your class from Application class (that I am writing). With this new class you only have to override the virtual methods (mainLoop, initialize and callbacks) and you will have a working application.

Here is the base class:

```
#pragma once

// Std library
#include <string>
// OpenGL related
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GLFW\glfw3.h>
// lh namespace
#include "camera.h"
#include "window.h"

namespace lh
{
    //!
    //! Class definition of a generic OpenGL Application. Receives the window size,
    //! the Application's name and OpenGL's version used.
    //!
    class Application
    {
    public:
        Application(int windowWidth, int windowHeight, std::string name, float versionOpenGL);
        virtual ~Application();
        void start();
    protected:
        virtual void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode) = 0;
        virtual void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos) = 0;
        virtual void scrollCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset) = 0;
        virtual void mainLoop() = 0;
        virtual void initialize() = 0;
    private:
        void execute();
        // Callbacks
        static void KeyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
        static void MouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
        static void ScrollCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
        // Attributes
        GLFWwindow* window_;
        int width_;
        int height_;
        std::string name_;
        int versionMajor_;
        int versionMinor_;
    };
}
```

So what I did is to declare as pure virtual functions all the functions needed to create in the derived class (that are located in `protected`). Here is the implementation:

```
void lh::Application::start()
{
    initialize();
    execute();
}

void lh::Application::execute()
{
    while (glfwWindowShouldClose(window_)) {
        glfwPollEvents();
        mainLoop();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window_);
    }
}
```

Basically the method `start` calls the virtual methods `initialize` and the method execute, that calls the method `mainLoop`. This way if I wanted to create something new, I wouldn't have to setup glfw and the window every time, I would just derive from this class and implement the pure virtual methods.

This is the idea, but Visual Studio reports an error that I am calling a pure virtual function, which probably means that I cannot do what I am currently doing. But I don't see another way of doing this (while making sure that the Application class remains abstract).

#### Note

I did not include all the implementation (constructors and callbacks) because I think they are irrelevant to the current problem (constructor is working fine).

#### EDIT

Here is how I am testing this class:

```
#pragma once
#include "application.h"

class Teste :
    public lh::Application
{
public:
    Teste(int width, int height, std::string name, float versionOpenGL);
    ~Teste();
protected:
    void keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode);
    void mouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos);
    void scrollCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset);
    void mainLoop();
    void initialize();
};
```

And the implementation:

```
#include "teste.h"
#include <iostream>

Teste::Teste(int width, int height, std::string name, float versionOpenGL) 
  : Application(width, height, name, versionOpenGL)
{
}

Teste::~Teste()
{
}

void Teste::initialize()
{
    std::cout << "INTIALIZE" << std::endl;
}

void Teste::mainLoop()
{
    std::cout << "AAAAAAAA" << std::endl;
}

void Teste::keyCallback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mode)
{

}

void Teste::mouseCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xpos, double ypos)
{

}

void Teste::scrollCallback(GLFWwindow* window, double xoffset, double yoffset)
{

}
```

#### EDIT:

The code above is working fine. The problem was that in the constructor I was calling `start()` at the end, which was calling the virtual methods. Removing it from the constructor and passing it to the main() function made it work fine.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: R6025
- pure virtual function call

Comment: As this class has purely virtual functions you cannot directly instantiate it. If you are trying to in order to test, that could cause a problem. Your other problem will be that when you derive a class from this class, `start()` will call `execute()` which is private in the base class and therefore not shared with child classes... not sure if that is intended.

Comment: But to answer a question you have, you can absolutely call purely virtual functions from the base class, and when you derive from that class and implement those functions the calls will be handled correctly in the derived class.

Comment: I added the code that I use for testing. Also the execute() method is private because I don't want the derived class to be able to call it. But if I change it to public the problem remains.

Comment: @RyanP First comment not relevant. Compiler would catch the problems you list and R6025 is a runtime error.

Comment: Looks good. Check to ensure the CPP file containing Teste is being compiled and linked.

Comment: What you want should be working (http://ideone.com/SKkuWf) The only reason I could currently think of is calling the virtual function in a constructor or destructor

Comment: ... so, what's in the constructor of Application?

Comment: ohhh, my constructor called start() at the end. I thought that there were no problems with that.

Comment: Debugger time. Visual Studio should stop dead and let you inspect when the exception hits.

Comment: I removed start() from the constructor and moved it to the main() and now it works.

Comment: Or maybe not. Sound's like you got it.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will edit it to not fool anyone

Comment: For fun, write yourself a simple base class and sub class that print out the name of the class in the constructors and destructors to see which order things get called. Should clear up any remaining questions you have.

Answer (score 0):

When C++ initializes a derived class (your Teste class ), it will first construct the base class (your Application class).
The derived class is not available when constructer of the base class is called. The virtual member funtion (execute) is still pure virtual, So the error is pure virtual function call.

Constructor should not call virtual function, because it will not provide polymorphism.You may provide a public start funtion of Application, and call it outside the constructor.

see: [Bjarne Stroustrup's C++ Style and Technique FAQ: Can I call a virtual function from a constructor?](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#vcall)